# Sort Order Items by “menu order” in WooCommerce order edit pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, product-variations

I use this function to sort Woocommerce order admin items by menu order but But products with variables do not display properly. And if there are several product with variables in the order, only one of them will be displayed.

edit: we have problem with multiple items of a product with different attributes:

item1: product A,variable a,attribute: red color, qty 12

item2: Product A, variable a, attribute: green color, qty 18

after sort it only shows :

item1: product A,variable a,attribute: red color, qty 12

In other words, product items with same variation id have problem.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_get_items', 'custom_woocommerce_order_get_items', 10, 2);


function custom_woocommerce_order_get_items($items, $object)
       {
           //no need to reorder if less than 2 products
           if(count($items)   <    2)
               return $items;
       
       //create a list of products within the order
       $products   =   array();
       foreach($items  as  $key    =>  $item)
           {
               $products[  $item['product_id']   ] =   $key;
           }
       
       $sorted_items  =   array();
       
       global $post;
           
       $args   =   array(
                           'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
                           'post_type'         =>  'product',
                           'orderby'           =>  'menu_order',
                           'order'             =>  'ASC',
                           'post__in'          =>  array_keys($products)
                           );
       $custom_query   =   new WP_Query($args);
       while($custom_query->have_posts())
           {
               $custom_query->the_post();
               $sorted_items[  $products[$post->ID]    ]   =   $items[ $products[$post->ID]    ];
           }
           
       //check for any left outside items
       foreach($items  as  $key    =>  $item)
           {
               if(isset($sorted_items[$key]))
                   $sorted_items[  $key   ]    =   $item;
           }
       
       return $sorted_items;
          
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:** (to include variations IDs when product it's a variable product)

The main issues in your code is in the query where you need to get the also `product_variation` post type and also in the first loop where you need to get the variation ID for variable products.

Also this code is outdated for WooCommerce 3+ as Order items are now a `WC_Order_Item_Product` Object and you need to use the available methods of this class instead.

You don't need the `global $post;` object as it's already as an argument in the function.

I have revisited all your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', 'filter_order_get_items', 10, 2 );
function filter_order_get_items( $items, $order ){

    // no need to reorder if less than 2 items
    if(count($items) < 2) return $items;

    $sorted_items = $products_items_ids = array();

    // Get the array of product/variation IDs with Item IDs within the order
    foreach( $items as $item_id => $item ){
        // Get the product ID (Added WC 3+ compatibility)
        $product_id = method_exists( $item, 'get_product_id' ) ? $item->get_product_id() : $item['product_id'];
        // Get the variation ID (Added WC 3+ compatibility)
        $variation_id = method_exists( $item, 'get_variation_id' ) ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item['variation_id'];
        if( $variation_id > 0 )
            $product_id = $variation_id;
        $products_items_ids[ $product_id ] = $item_id;
    }

    // The WP Query based on the product Ids from this order
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
       'posts_per_page'  =>  -1,
       'post_type'       =>  array( 'product', 'product_variation' ), // <== HERE MISSING
       'orderby'         =>  'menu_order',
       'order'           =>  'ASC',
       'post__in'        =>  array_keys( $products_items_ids ),
    ) );

    // Loop in the Query
    if( $query->have_posts() ){
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            // Get the post ID
            $post_id = $query->post->ID;

            // Get the corresponding item ID for the current product ID
            $item_id = $products_items_ids[ $post_id ];

            // Get the new sorted array of items
            $sorted_items[$item_id] = $items[$item_id];
        endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();

    return $sorted_items;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme) or in any plugin file.*

Tested and works for all products including product variations on WooCommerce v2.5.x to v3.2+

Comment: we still have problem with multiple items of a product with different attributes:
product A,variable a,attribute: red color, qty 12
Product A, variable a, attribute: green color, qty 18
after sort it only shows : product A,variable a,attribute: red color, qty 12
thank you @loictheaztec

Comment: please test and order with two items of one product of one variable of two attributes like color(item1: red item 2: green). sorry for my poor english.

Comment: @Amirrajaeizadeh Ok see the problem… I have updated my code and this time is working perfecly

Comment: Unfortunately, we still have problems with the order of a product in two colors(one variable). see https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/any-color-any-size.png @loictheaztec

Comment: For me it's working for multiple variations of a variable product too, just as you pointed: see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/koQEE.png … I have paste back the code that I have and that is working for me, so try it again please

Comment: Thank you, it works just with items with different variation id. When two items have same variation id only shows one of them. Please order a variable product with one variation that select all color. (A variable with "any color" value)  @loictheaztec

Comment: @Amirrajaeizadeh in WooCommerce if you add 2 times the same variation to cart, it just increase the quantity. So in WC Orders you don't have 2 times the same variation ID as 2 separated order items… This can only happen with product custom fields and if it's the case you should have mentioned it in your question…

Comment: Variation is same, attribute is different . I will back soon

Comment: Is better you contact me on skype chat, my ID is `marsloic` … When I set a product variation with any / any it's not enable for add to cart… So how you get that as an order item?

Comment: please see this pdf:
https://babymama.ir/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/variation_problem.pdf

Comment: Did you get a result? @loictheaztec

Comment: @Amirrajaeizadeh No I can't get this work for your specific case… I even don't know how you do that…